# Separating a number into groups of three

Tags: algorithm

consider this number:`785462454105`,I need an algorithm that first separates the number into groups with maximum length of three(starting from the right side) ,it would look something like:

```
a = 105
b = 454
c = 462
d = 785
```

Of course I know I can convert the number to string but I want to do this without any conversion. Also I'm not allowed to use any arrays and any special methods or class which exist in the programming language use(I'm using java but as I said I'm not allowed to use the functions).The only tools I have are loops,conditional clauses and mathematical,arithmetic and logical operators.
Also it is possible to get `454000` or `462000000` out using loops but how can I get rid of the zeros?
Note that something like `1234` should turn to:

```
a = 234
b = 1
```

Comment: You might want to think about the binary representation of your number and then apply "masks" to get each of the four parts.  Kind of like IPv4 netmask work.

Comment: @RedCricket can you elaborate?

Comment: @RedCricket that wouldnt work

Comment: If you divide by 1000 and take the remainder, you get 105. The quotient is 785462454. Divide that by 1000 and take the remainder, lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Say x=785462454105. x%1000/1 = 105. x%1000000/1000 = 454. x%1000000000/1000000 = 462. etc...

Comment: @juvian of course if would work, but I think Jim's solution is better.

Comment: @RedCricket there is no bit mask that gives last 3 digits, as 1000 is no a power of 2. If you mean using multiple mask operations to get them, then yes it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to get a group of last 3 digits if you take a remainder while dividing by 1000.

`785462454105 % 1000 == 105`

Then you could get rid of last 3 digits dividing by 1000:

`785462454105 / 1000 == 785462454`

Repeat this in a loop until the number becomes zero and you're done.

The only issue left is to print leading zeros:
`123045 % 1000 = 45` but we want to print 045.

Usually you'll need a separate inner loop, for example, to count decimal digits (dividing by 10 until it becomes zero) and then print number of missing zeros (it's equal to number of digits you want minus number of digits in your number).

But here it's a simple case, you could just sole it via couple of `if`s:

```
long a = 785462454105;
while (a > 0) {
  long x = a % 1000;
  a /= 1000;
  if (x < 10) {
    System.out.print("00");
  } else if (x < 100) {
    System.out.print("0");
  }
  System.out.println(x);
}
```